# How to fit intensity peaks from a image?

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, nonlinear-regression

I have an image that I can convert to a text file / table of intensities. In this image, several regions show higher intensity, i.e., a peak. A peak may be stored in a 10x10 matrix with rows and columns corresponding to the x1, x2 coordinates in the image. Basically my data looks like the two-dimensional normal distribution in the first plot of [this pdf](http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/misc/Plotting_3d_in_R.pdf). I want to know the center of the peak and the full width half maximum for each of those matrices.

What should be the approach assuming that I can approximate this matrices to a multidimensional Gaussian? I have z, x1 and x2, but I would like to get the regression parameters.

Comment: You would do best to edit your Q & have it re-opened, rather than delete it & ask another. If you delete enough of your questions, the SE software will automatically (& irrevocably) ban you.

Comment: Is the idea here that you think the intensities are a non-linear function of the (x1, x2) coordinates, where the function in question takes the form of a multivariate Gaussian? What do you think the nature of the error distribution would be, also Gaussian?

Comment: @gung First,thanks a lot for the feedback. I though that, since it was out of scope, would be easier just to open a new one. 

About the function. Yes, it will assume the form of a multivariate Gaussian and the error will also be Gaussian. So, yes for both questions. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is fit a nonlinear regression model where the intensity is the response as a function of the `x1`, `x2` coordinates.  The functional form will be the PDF of a multivariate normal.  In R, you can use [?nls](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nls.html) to do this.  You can write the function yourself, but for convenience you may prefer to use [?dmvnorm](http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/mvtnorm/html/Mvnorm.html) from the [mvtnorm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html).  Here is a simplified example:

```
library(mvtnorm)  # for dmvnorm
set.seed(7124)    # this will make the code exactly reproducible
d = expand.grid(x1=1:10, x2=1:10)
i = dmvnorm(as.matrix(d), mean=c(2.5, 3), sigma=rbind(c( 1.0, -0.6),
                                                      c(-0.6,  1.0) ) )
e = rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=0.1)
y = 5 + 40*i + e;  d$y = y

round(matrix(i, nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow=F), 2)  # output omitted
round(matrix(y, nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow=F), 2)  # output omitted

mvn = function(m1, m2, v1, v2, cv12){  # you need this function for nls()
  y = dmvnorm(as.matrix(d[,1:2]), mean=c(m1, m2), sigma=rbind(c(v1,  cv12),
                                                              c(cv12,  v2) ))
  return(y)
}
mod = nls(y~b0+b1*mvn(m1, m2, v1, v2, cv12), d, algorithm="port",
          start=list(b0=mean(y), b1=diff(range(y)), 
                     m1=d[which.max(d$y),1], m2=d[which.max(d$y),2], 
                     v1=10, v2=10, cv12=0))
summary(mod)
# 
# Parameters:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# b0    4.99398    0.01112  449.02   <2e-16 ***
# b1   39.27467    0.50379   77.96   <2e-16 ***
# m1    2.49315    0.01129  220.87   <2e-16 ***
# m2    3.00054    0.01143  262.58   <2e-16 ***
# v1    0.96444    0.02354   40.97   <2e-16 ***
# v2    0.99235    0.02332   42.55   <2e-16 ***
# cv12 -0.58553    0.01913  -30.60   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Residual standard error: 0.1012 on 93 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: Looks like what I wanted!

Comment: When running this with my data, I' getting  
Convergence failure: iteration limit reached without convergence (10). Any suggestion?
Depending of some adjusts, I get Convergence failure: singular convergence (7).

Comment: @vcaldas, how well the code will work depends strongly on the quality of your starting values.  I tried to come up with some strategies that will make the code more robust, but it's hard to do that specifically for your data. You may have to tinker with it.