# Bell-curve shape regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I am trying to fit some data that looks like a bell-curve: we reach a maximum at some value close to the mean, then the graph falls towards zero as we get further away from it. I am not the "owner" of the data so I cannot share it with you here, but I think the idea is clear with the "fake data" below

I would like to find a non-linear model that can fit that type of data, but my search did not give me much information. What are your suggestions?

[image: The data looks something like this]

Comment: Have you tried a regular linear model already? How were the residuals? Also, is your real data also bounded in 0 and 1000?

Comment: @user2974951 The data is in principle not bounded, but we would get all zeros if we go too much beyond. A regular linear model does not work here as there is no upward/downward trend

Comment: @David If you have other variables try a regular linear model first and check the residuals. If this is all the data that you have then, as mkt suggested, try a GAM model.

Comment: @user2974951 There are no other predictors. All the data is plotted there

Comment: The answer depends both on what exactly the shape might be and on assumptions about variations around the shape.  Absent any such specific information, threads that provide *any* solution have to be considered duplicates.  Here's a good search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+fit+gaussian+curve+answers%3A1

Comment: Do you just need a model that fits these data, or do you very specifically need to estimate the parameters, $\mu$, $\sigma^2$, & a vertical shift &/or expansion, that correspond to these data? In addition, what are these data? That will help identify what should be done. Can they go below $0$? With the data bunching up at $0$, it doesn't seem that the residuals of any model are likely to be very normal.

Comment: Related: [How to fit intensity peaks from a image?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153421/7290)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to just describe the pattern, you could try a GAMM i.e. generalized additive mixed model. Choose the residual distribution to reflect the zero bound and any other data properties you may be aware of.

Comment: Why should I use an additive model when I have only one predictor? Also, what residual distribution should I use?

Comment: @David You may not need the additivity, but GAM(M)s are a convenient way to fit smooth responses. Splines, etc do the same, but GAMMs offer you the added benefit of allowing you to pick your distribution. I can't propose one without a more detailed description of your data and its properties (which you can edit into the question, if you want to).

Comment: What would you do if, for instance you knew $y=f(x)$ where $f$ follows the shape of a normal-distribution density function?

Comment: @David If you have a good reason to expect that the response shape is captured by a specific equation/functional form, just fit that. But if you're just eyeballing it and deciding that it looks normal-ish, you don't lose much by using a GAM. It's your call and depends on your reasoning, goals and the nature of the data. FWIW, calling this a normal distribution doesn't obviously make sense to me here.